# AirPort Extreme - LAN ports active in range-extender mode?

Tags: wireless-bridge, repeater, apple

I've got a 5th gen Airport Extreme (MD031LL/A) working well in the back room.  If I install a 2nd in the front room as a repeater/extender, will the front room LAN ports be active and participate in all the DHCP goodness, etc?

In other words, can the 2nd Airport act as a bridge as well as a wireless range extender?